# Why is behavior different for ember serve vs index.html?

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm using `ember-cli 0.0.33`

I created a default app using

```
ember new stealth
```

Then I built it using

```
ember build --environment=production
```

Then I uploaded the `index` file to `https://d1mungh8jer63d.cloudfront.net/index.html` and `asset` files to `../assets/*` and then opened the `index` url in `Chrome` and `Firefox` and got a blank white screen on both.

Next, without changing anything, I ran

```
ember s --environment=production --live-reload=false
```

Which gives me the exact same `dist` files. I open my browser to `localhost:4200` and the page had `Welcome to Ember.js`.

But both `index.html` and `localhost:4200` have the same source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Stealth</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <base href="/" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d1mungh8jer63d.cloudfront.net/assets/vendor-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d1mungh8jer63d.cloudfront.net/assets/stealth-de3c495d5da3bffcdc865aaa60f76ab3.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      window.StealthENV = {"baseURL":"/","locationType":"auto","EmberENV":{"FEATURES":{}},"APP":{}};
      window.EmberENV = window.StealthENV.EmberENV;
    </script>
    <script src="https://d1mungh8jer63d.cloudfront.net/assets/vendor-5429f75166356b28c3e42dd401abaf36.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d1mungh8jer63d.cloudfront.net/assets/stealth-271c63d147abd689113e3c0bae25a9e5.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.Stealth = require('stealth/app')['default'].create(StealthENV.APP);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why did one "work"/display `Welcome to Ember.js`, while the other just displayed a blank white screen? And how do I make `index.html` "work"?

Comment: Anything in the console on the server?

Comment: `version: 0.0.33
Serving on http://0.0.0.0:4200

Build successful - 5304ms.

Slowest Trees                  | Total          
-------------------------------+----------------
UglifyJSFilter                 | 5025ms`

Comment: Yeah I am getting the same issue when loading `index.html`. @Derek have you been able to solve this problem?

Comment: [Created an issue on github](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/1098)

Answer (score 3):

(The OP was able to resolve his own problem. I'm just pasting his own answer here, so it can be found)

If you need to deploy your ember project to a subdirectory, use the [`baseUrl`](http://www.ember-cli.com/#history-api-and-base-url) configuration.